# Possible Growth Function for a hypothesis set

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to ML and I am trying to resolve a Homework problem. How do I determine the possible growth function $m_H(N)$ for some hypothesis set? If my choices are $1,2^N,2^{\sqrt{N}},N^2-N+2$ and none.

My research : I understand that the growth function counts the most dichotomies on any N points and the growth function satisfies $m_H(N) \le 2^N$.

Also $m_H(3) = 2^3 = 8. m_H(4) = 14 < 2^4$. Where $H$ is the perceptron. Any leads on how I can resolve the question is really appreciated.

Thanks